# Парсинг сайта simplehtmlDOM

Tags: php, dom, синтаксический-анализ

Задача состоит в парсинге категории с одного сайта.

1. Заходим на сайт, выбираем все ссылки на марки авто(сайт по продаже автозапчастей).
2. Сохраняем все ссылки в файл /index.php
3. Проходим на каждую ссылку, копируем путь, создаем папку из этого пути
4. Копируем все ссылки на модели авто в файл путь/index.php
5. Переходим в каждую модель, далее все аналогично п.4

Повторяем до конца каталога и в итоге сохраняем последнюю страницу в index.php. Есть вот что:

```
<?php
ini_set("max_execution_time", 3600);

$custom_url = 'http://exist.ru/cat/TO';
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
//Main Function
function categories_parse($custom_url)
{
$header_m = '<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Демонстрационная версия продукта «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом»");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("NOT_SHOW_NAV_CHAIN", "Y");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Главная страница");
?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
"AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
"PATH" => "/bitrix/templates/4/include_areas/show.php",
"EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
),false);
session_start();

process_form();

?>';

    $footer_m = '<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>';

    $a           = 0;
    $i           = 0;
    $parse_url   = file_get_html($custom_url);
    $parse       = $parse_url->find('div.catalog-column a');
    $catalog_col = $parse_url->find('div.catalog-column');
    foreach ($catalog_col as $col) {
        $catalog_col_m[$a] = $col->innertext;
        $file_main         = fopen('./index.php', 'w');
        fwrite($file_main, $header_m);
        fwrite($file_main, $catalog_col_m[$a]);
        fwrite($file_main, $footer_m);
        $a++;
    }
    foreach ($parse as $p) {
        $category_href_original[$i] = $p->href;
        $categoty_path[$i]          = "." . $category_href_original[$i];
        mkdir($categoty_path[$i], 0777, true);
        $category_href[$i] = 'http://exist.ru' . $p->href;
        model_parse($category_href[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}

function model_parse($href)
{
    $model_url  = file_get_html($href);
    $i          = 0;
    $model_link = $model_url->find('div.cell a');
    $model_c    = $model_url->find('div.cell');
    $z          = 0;
    foreach ($model_c as $cell) {
        $file_c_p        = $href . 'index.php';
        $file_c          = fopen($file_c_p, 'w');
        $model_col_m[$z] = $cell->innertext;
        fwrite($file_c, $header_c);
        fwrite($file_c, $model_col_m[$z]);
        fwrite($file_c, $footer_c);
        $z++;
    }
    foreach ($model_link as $lnk) {
        $model_href_original[$i] = $lnk->href;
        $model_path[$i]          = "." . $model_href_original[$i];
        $model_href[$i]          = 'http://exist.ru' . $lnk->href;
        mkdir($model_path[$i], 0777, true);
        price_cat_parse($model_href[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}

function price_cat_parse($price_cat_href)
{
    $header_parse = '<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Демонстрационная версия продукта «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом»");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("NOT_SHOW_NAV_CHAIN", "Y");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Главная страница");

?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
"AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
"PATH" => "/bitrix/templates/4/include_areas/show.php",
"EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
),false);
session_start();

process_form();

?>';

    $footer_parse = '<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>';

    $price_cat_href_n  = $price_cat_href . 'index.php';
    $price_cat_url     = file_get_html($price_cat_href);
    $price_cat_lnk     = $price_cat_url->find('.content-ul a');
    $price_cat_content = $price_cat_url->find('tr', 0);
    $i                 = 0;
    $h                 = 0;
    $file_p_c          = fopen($price_cat_href_n, 'w');
    foreach ($price_cat_content as $cat_cont) {
        $price_cont[$h] = $cat_cont->innertext;
        fwrite($file_c, $header_parse);
        fwrite($file_c, $price_cont[$h]);
        fwrite($file_c, $footer_parse);
        $h++;
    }

    foreach ($price_cat_lnk as $lnk) {
        $price_cat_href_original[$i] = $lnk->href;
        $price_cat_path[$i]          = "." . $price_cat_href_original[$i];
        $price_cat_href[$i]          = 'http://exist.ru' . "$price_cat_href_original[$i]";
        // echo "$price_cat_href_n[$i] \n";
        mkdir($price_cat_path[$i], 0777, true);
        price_parse($price_cat_href[$i], $price_cat_path[$i]);
        $i++;

    }
}

function price_parse($price_href, $folder_file)
{
    $header = '<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Демонстрационная версия продукта «1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом»");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("NOT_SHOW_NAV_CHAIN", "Y");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Главная страница");

?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
"AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
"PATH" => "/bitrix/templates/4/include_areas/show.php",
"EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
),false);
session_start();

process_form();

?>';
    $footer = '<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>';

    $price_new_url = file_get_html($price_href);
    $price_cont    = $price_new_url->find('table.tbl');
    $i             = 0;

    foreach ($price_cont as $cont) {
        $index                       = '/index.php';
        $path_to_file                = $folder_file . $index;
        $price_contnent_original[$i] = fopen($path_to_file, 'w+');
        fwrite($price_contnent_original[$i], $header);
        fwrite($price_contnent_original[$i], $cont);
        fwrite($price_contnent_original[$i], $footer);
        echo "$path_to_file \n";
        echo "file wrote \n";
        $i++;

    }
}

categories_parse($custom_url);
?>
```

Помогите, кто чем может....

Comment: В чём собственно вопрос? Что вы пытались сделать сами?

Comment: да, действительно, может будет вопрос, а то "Помогите, кто чем может...." - денег дать? :)

Comment: Вопрос в том, что почему то не сохраняются файлы index.php. Права доступа в полном порядке.
"Что вы пытались сделать сами?" Все что выше написано, то и делал сам.

Может у кого есть идея как это реализовать получше?

Comment: еще, из за вложенности цикла время выполнения получается огромным.

Answer (score 3):

По опыту вытягивания и парсинга данных выборов с сайта избиркома, могу порекомендовать вот что:

1. Разбить задачу на два отдельных этапа: скачивание файлов из нета, и их разбор;
2. Скачивать быстрее, используюя параллельность запросов [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php);